# XUL standalone application not starting

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I recently took on a project built on XUL (standalone, using xulrunner) - However I can't get it to properly run.
I'm getting this error when I attempt to start it using the command line (`xulrunner.exe ../application.ini -jsconsole`):

> No chrome package registered for chrome://case_scenario_builder/content/case_scenario_builder.xul

The `chrome.manifest` file looks like this:

```
content case_scenario_builder file:chrome/case_scenario_builder/content/ contentaccessible=yes
content jslib jar:chrome/jslib.jar!/ 
skin case_scenario_builder skin file:chrome/case_scenario_builder/skin/
locale case_scenario_builder en-US chrome/case_scenario_builder/locale/en-US/
```

Any ideas on where I could start debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your manifest just isn't getting loaded. To test that I'd introduce an intentional syntax error and check the error console. E.g. if you put

```
asdfasd
```

on its own line, you should get a `Warning: Ignoring unrecognized chrome manifest directive 'asdfasd'.` in the Error console.

(Note to other experts: initially I wanted to suggest dropping 'file:' prefix and avoiding underscores in the package name, but I tested it on a Firefox nightly, and it works fine.)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!
In case anyone else runs into this as well:
It was due to the caching system in place by default and the use of .jar containers instead of folders.
The XUL environment had cached both JS and XUL files - and even after disabling those, I had to extract everything that was in the .jar file to the content folder and update the chrome.manifest file.

Thanks for your suggestions on debugging! - they helped the process.

Answer (score 0):

Your chrome package clearly didn't get registered. From what I can tell, the reason is the bogus `file:` prefix, you should drop it when specifying relative paths:

```
content case_scenario_builder chrome/case_scenario_builder/content/ contentaccessible=yes
```

Btw, I suspect that you copied `contentaccessible=yes` from somewhere - you should drop it as well unless you know what it does.

Comment: That was my first idea too, but specifying a relative URL with the `file:` prefix worked in my testing...

Comment: Wow, I knew that the manifest parser had some strange special handling for `jar:` URLs but apparently it does something to `file:` URLs as well - didn't know that :)